# How to identify group by with rollup null in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb, rollup

How can I distinguish a null representing the set of all values in a superaggregate row from a null in a regular row?

For example in Oracle I can use a GROUPING function for it.

In MariaDB I tried to use the following:

```
if(<some_column> is null and count(1)>1,1,0)
```

But it doesn't work in all cases.

For example tab_a table:

```
create table tab_a (col1 integer, col2 integer);
insert into tab_a values (5,1), (10,2), (15,null);
```

This next query correctly determined the grouping null:

```
select sum(col1), col2,
    if(col2 is null and count(1)>1,'grouping null','not grouping null'), 
count(1) from tab_a group by col2 with rollup
```

Result:

```
'15', NULL, 'not grouping null', '1'
'5',  '1',  'not grouping null', '1'
'10', '2',  'not grouping null', '1'
'30', NULL, 'grouping null',     '3'
```

But this query doesn't identify the grouping null:

```
select sum(col1), round(col2),
    if(round(col2) is null and count(1)>1,'grouping null','not grouping null'), 
count(1) from tab_a group by round(col2) with rollup
```

Result:

```
'15', NULL, 'not grouping null', '1'
'5',  '1',  'not grouping null', '1'
'10', '2',  'not grouping null', '1'
'30', NULL, 'not grouping null', '3'
```

Why doesn't the second query work and what is a solution that will work in all cases?

**UPDATE:** Also I tried to use COALESCE but it helped to determine only simple null, but I need to change column where GROUP BY ROLLUP NULL is there.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what nulls can be in the input. As well as any other constraints. (Part of a [mcve].)

Comment: Check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Please google many clear, concise phrasings of a problem/question/goal before you ask; use one as title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinguish between NULL's when using "group by ... with rollup"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200516/distinguish-between-nulls-when-using-group-by-with-rollup)

Comment: You can use another approach, like `select *,if(rounded is null and counted>1,'grouping null','not grouping null') from (select sum(col1) summed, round(col2) rounded, count(1) counted from tab_a group by round(col2) with rollup)cs`

Comment: @Hackerman, yes, this is the only one solution that works properly in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @Evgenia, glad to help :)